# GCM the right way to implement turn based multiplayer in GAE + Android

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging, throttling

I am currently developing an android game that is turnbased and uses GAE on the server side. Now until now I used GCM to notify when it is a players turn to act, but I came across some threads, that said GCM throttles a lot (speaking about 20 initial tokens for each collapse key and after that you get 1 token back every 3 minutes). But those were threads in which the information was based on users experiences. Now my question is - since I did not find anything official about that, only that throttling "exists" - does anyone know some more "hard facts" or is this the right approach I want to use? 
Moves are made between 2 players, and can be as frequent as 1 move every two seconds down to a move a day. I am worried, that people can play quite fast, and then such a restriction would kick in ...
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

GCM also doesn't guarantee message delivery.  I would build some smart polling into the app.  Maybe something that polls every second for the first 5 seconds or so and drops off, and use GCM when the response time has been longer than a 5 seconds.

Comment: I am currently thinking about using my own server for kind of "push-style" notifications. Clients would keep an connection open to that server for something like 5 minutes. On GAE within the first four minutes after any response I would use an URLFetch to that server which translates that and sends that via the open connection to the client. Or when the response took longer than 4/5 minutes I would then use GCM. But this way is kind of strange, and especially it does not "scale" very well, which was why I chose GAE in the first place. Any suggestions on that?